# Load raster as matrix

Tags: r, raster

Is there an easy way to load a raster directly into R as a matrix, instead of loading the raster, then using `as.matrix()` to transform it into a matrix, i.e.

```
myras <- raster("file.tif")
mymat <- as.matrix(myras)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution would be to use `as` like this:

```
library(raster)
mymat <- as(raster("file.tif"), "matrix")
```

Keep in mind, that reading a matrix directly from a file is not always an option. Since you are using a tiff file, you might have a *compressed* raster (e.g. by LZW, Packbits, etc.). Thus it is necessary to load and uncompress the raster first, before accessing the raster values and transform them into a `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

There are similar alternatives, but I do not think there is an easier way. (except perhaps for png and some other graphics formats?). Without further explanation, it seems an odd question, as what you show is very concise. You can combine your two statements into one line (adding 8 characters to as.matrix)

```
library(raster)
myras <- as.matrix(raster("file.tif"))
```

Comment: Thanks Robert.  I'm working with very large rasters, but really only need them in matrix format.  I was wondering if there was a faster way to load the data, i.e. skip the `raster()` step and jump straight to the `mymat@data`.